# Can I run a service on the side of Outlook email server ? Also, can I embed HTML page with dynamic buttons in email ?

Tags: javascript, html, outlook

We are working on a project where I need to run a service on outlook email server. Let me explain!

We have to integrate a workflow with Outlook. So, if the user has a task assigned where he/she might have to approve/deny/reject an approval request, he/she should be able to do the same from outlook itself. So in the mail, itself buttons will be present to complete the task and user will not have to log in to perform the task.

Now user need not be on the same network all the time. He/she should be able to use their mobile network to perform the same task.

So is there a way to just perform the task and let it sit on outlook email server? and we keep running a service on email server which would contact our network whenever possible and send the appropriate request?

Also, how can we add dynamic buttons to email? Should we create a HTML and embed in email? Can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to develop an Outlook add-in which can communicate with your web service and reflect the data retrieved in Outlook dynamically. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook) to get started quickly.

You can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures in COM add-ins. For each of the callbacks the add-in implements, the responses are cached. For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in-place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate.aspx) method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v%3Doffice.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v%3Doffice.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))